# make field group repeatable

Tags: entities

I am using [Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module and I would like to make certain group repeatable if needed, like adding a plus (+) icon next to it. Is that possible? and how?

Comment: I'd look into https://drupal.org/project/field_collection or https://drupal.org/project/field_group_multiple as possible module solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. It allows you to group fields and add more of these "collections" inside the same node. Works great for slideshows for instance when you don't know how many images the site editor wants to use and you need custom fields (like big headline, small headline, promo text, link etc) grouped with the image.